# Why is final the only modifier for local variables in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        private int x = 10;
        public int y = 20;
        protected int z = 30;
        static int w = 40;  
        final int i = 50;
    }
}
```

The **only applicable modifier is final** here; **for other modifiers**, the program gives **compiler errors**. Why is that? Please explain in detail.

Comment: Because those are local variables, local to the `main` method that is. In that context, only `final` makes sense.

Comment: The other modifiers are in the function. You can't have a non static variable inside a static method.

Comment: don't forget about `volatile` and `transient` :) `static` is btw a valid modifier for local variables in `C` iirc.

Comment: what about *int a = 60;* ?

Answer (score 11):

In short - none of the other modifiers make sense in that context.  Saying a variable is `public`, `private`, `protected`, or `static` simply doesn't make sense in the context of a local variable that will go out of scope (and be garbage collected) once the method exits.  Those modifiers are intended for class *fields* (and methods), to define their visibility (or in the case of `static`, their scope).

`final` is the only one that makes sense in the context of a local variable because all it means is that the variable cannot be modified after its initial declaration, it has nothing to do with access control.

Comment: `static` kind of makes sense, and other programming languages allow it on local variables to say that after a function exits, the variable retains its value for the next time it's called.  I personally think that using this feature is horrible practice.

Comment: @ajb Other languages allow it (I believe C++ is one) but it's a horrible practice to use it.  While no language can totally eliminate all horrible programming practices (Make it idiot proof, somebody'll make a better idiot), the designers of Java did do their best to eliminate as many as they reasonably could.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that all those declarations are local variable declarations.

For some more details, always go to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) which states a local variable can be made up of

```
LocalVariableDeclarationStatement:
    LocalVariableDeclaration ;

LocalVariableDeclaration:
    VariableModifiersopt Type VariableDeclarators
```

where

```
VariableModifiers:
    VariableModifier
    VariableModifiers VariableModifier

VariableModifier: one of
    Annotation final

VariableDeclarators:
    VariableDeclarator
    VariableDeclarators , VariableDeclarator

VariableDeclarator:
    VariableDeclaratorId
    VariableDeclaratorId = VariableInitializer

VariableDeclaratorId:
    Identifier
    VariableDeclaratorId []

VariableInitializer:
    Expression
    ArrayInitializer
```

So the only acceptable `VariableModifier` is `final` (and an annotation, which is rare).

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the other modifiers apply to classes rather than methods.

A private, protected or public modifier affects the visibility of global variables to objects of other classes, so using those modifiers for local variables is non-sensical.

A static modifier declares a global variable to belong to a class rather than objects of a class, so using them for local variables does not make sense either.

The only modifier that makes sense is "final", which ensures a local variable does not change within the method.